Cypress Testing Error: getResult() Method Returns undefined for Canvas Element in vue-advanced-cropper
I am writing a test for the image cropping functionality in my Vue application using the vue-advanced-cropper package. I have encountered an issue where the getResult() method, which retrieves the canvas element, returns undefined during Cypress tests. However, it works correctly when running the application locally.
How to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Here is the link to use getResult() method:

vue-advanced-cropper - getresult method

Below is the screenshot or code of the issue:

code:crop-img-component
<template>
  <div class="mt-8">
    <div :style="{ width: `${cropWrapperWidth}px` }" class="max-h-70vh overflow-y-scroll scroll-wrap">
      <Cropper
        data-test="cropper-container"
        ref="cropperBox"
        :src="customImage"
        :stencil-component="CircleStencil"
        :canvas="canvasLimit"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="flex mt-4 justify-center">
      <button data-test="crop-img-confirm" class="w-20 highlight-btn" @click="checkCrop">確定</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { Cropper, CircleStencil } from 'vue-advanced-cropper';
import 'vue-advanced-cropper/dist/style.css';

export default {
  components: {
    Cropper,
  },
  emits: ['close'],
  props: {
    customImage: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    cropWrapperWidth: {
      type: Number,
      default: 600,
    },
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const cropperBox = ref(null);

    //  限制圖片裁切後範圍
    const canvasLimit = {
      maxWidth: 600,
      maxHeight: 600,
    };

    const checkCrop = () => {
      const { canvas } = cropperBox.value.getResult();

      canvas.toBlob(
        blob => {
          const imgFile = new File([blob], 'agent.png', {
            type: 'image/png',
          });

          emit('close', imgFile);
        },
        'image/png',
        0.8
      );
    };

    return {
      CircleStencil,
      cropperBox,
      checkCrop,
      canvasLimit,
    };
  },
};
</script>


test cypress code:crop-img
describe('upload image', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      initPage('None', null);
      cy.get('[data-test="member-upload-picture"] input').selectFile(
        [
          {
            contents: 'cypress/fixtures/member/account/lazy-bear.jpg',
          },
        ],
        { force: true }
      );
    });
    it('click confirm button, should upload image', () => {
      cy.get('[data-test="cropper-container"]').as('cropper-container');
      cy.get('@cropper-container').should('exist');
      cy.get('[data-test="crop-img-confirm"]').click();
    });
});


cypress test ui env
cypress test ui env
local env
local env
